# Groovy/Grails - Modify dynamic array based on content

Tags: arrays, groovy, grails-2.5

I have an array, which I get from a web service so it's always different but looks like this:

```
def originalArray = [
        [startDate:7 October 2017, endDate:14 October 2017, type:A],
        [startDate:7 October 2017, endDate:9 October 2017, type:A],
        [startDate:9 October 2017, endDate:14 October 2017, type:A],

        [startDate:7 October 2017, endDate:14 October 2017, type:B],

        [startDate:7 October 2017, endDate:9 October 2017, type:C],
        [startDate:9 October 2017, endDate:14 October 2017, type:C]]
```

Don't mind the date "formats" used, I'm writing it like that to simplify this question. What I'm trying to do is filter this array by *type* but also when there's occurrences where there's a fullweek, midweek and weekend that all occur across the same week and have the same *type* it should remove the midweek and weekend and give the fullweek a property called *splittable* set to true. So the above example will end up looking like this:

```
def moddedArray = [
    [startDate:7 October 2017, endDate:14 October 2017, type:A, splittable:true],

    [startDate:7 October 2017, endDate:14 October 2017, type:B, splittable:false],

    [startDate:7 October 2017, endDate:9 October 2017, type:C, splittable:false],
    [startDate:9 October 2017, endDate:14 October 2017, type:C, splittable:false]]
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
function startingFunction() {
    def weeks = getWeeks() // gets the array
    def fullWeeks = []
    weeks.each {
        def days = it.endDate - it.startDate
        if(days == 7) {
            fullWeeks.add(it)
        }
    }

    if(fullWeeks) {
        return applySplittable(fullWeeks,weeks)
    } else {
        return weeks
    }
}

function applySplittable(fullweeks,weeks) {
    def prelimWeeks = []
    def weeksSinglesRemoved = []

    fullweeks.eachWithIndex { f, i ->
        weeks.eachWithIndex { w, j ->
            if(!(f.type == w.type && (f.startDate == w.startDate || f.endDate == w.endDate) && (!(f.startDate == w.startDate && f.endDate == w.endDate)))) {
                prelimWeeks.add(w)
            }
        }
    }

    prelimWeeks.each { // when it gets here all the weeks will have been added as many times as there fullweeks, unless it's a midweek or weekend that have a fullweek
        if(Collections.frequency(prelimWeeks,it) >= fullweeks.size()) {
            weeksSinglesRemoved.add(it)
        }
    }

    return weeksSinglesRemoved.unique()
}
```

So as you can see, what I've tried is a mess and is probably not even that efficient but it works to remove the midweeks and weekends if there's a fullweek but it doesn't apply the splittable property. If anyone can provide me a way to get this done as simply as possible. Let me know if I need to supply more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the `applySplittable` function, it now looks like this:

```
def applySplittable(fullweeks, weeks) {
    def weeksSplit = []
    weeks.eachWithIndex { w, i ->
        def days = w.endDate - w.startDate
        if(days != 7) {
            def hasFull = fullweeks.findAll { w.type == it.type && (w.startDate == it.startDate || w.endDate == it.endDate) }
            if(!hasFull) {
                w.splittable = false
                weeksSplit.add(w)
            }
        } else {
            def hasSplit = weeks.findAll { w.type == it.type && (w.startDate == it.startDate || w.endDate == it.endDate) && !(w.startDate == it.startDate && w.endDate == it.endDate) }
            if(hasSplit) {
                w.splittable = true
            } else {
                w.splittable = false
            }
            weeksSplit.add(w)
        }
    }
    return weeksSplit
}
```

It's still a mess and it's probably still pretty inefficient but it seems to be working.